# Facebook login with IE11

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-11, facebook-login, windows-10

Trying to login to Facebook from my app using the following code -

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');

        });
    } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
}, { scope: 'email, public_profile' });
```

It worked fine with IE11 until I upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Now it opens the FB login dialog, I sign in with my credentials and the dialog does not close and I am not signed in.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Open developer tools (F12) and see what's happening on the console. And probably share that with us ... ;-)

Comment: @AxelAmthor, Using the developer tool there is nothing really to see, it start by showing a regular FB login dialog and after I fill in my credentials and click the **Log in** button I get, in the same windows/dialog, an empty page...

Comment: I also tried to reset IE11 and to clear history and cookies but still I can't sign in using the code in my question.

Comment: If I cancel the Facebook login dialog I get the following message -
**SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone. See the Facebook Help Centerfor more information.**

I don't understand what it means.

Comment: I also enabled SSL for the project and browse is with the SSL address but still it behave the same....